# AutoComplete Stopping When User Presses "Enter"

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the AutoCompleteExtender on a commercial site. My problem is the users are quickly typing in part of a word and immediately pressing "Enter" which causes the AutoComplete control to *NOT* come back with a list of suggestions. For example, if my database has the phrase "Texas, United States" in it but the users just type "Texas" quickly followed by Enter then the dropdown list does not appear.

What I would like is for the AutoComplete control to ignore the fact the user has pressed Enter and go and fetch the suggested data anyway. (The ultimate would be if it ignored Enter when there was currently no list, but selected an item when there was a list).

I can simulate this exact problem by going to the samples section of this Microsoft ASP.NET site and typing in some characters very quickly followed by 'Enter'.

Please could someone tell me what I need to do?

Thanks, Martin

Comment: Your premise might be flawed.  Users who type in a few characters and press the Enter key are clear about what they want.  Why force them to see a list when they believe they do not need it?

Comment: There are a couple of scenarios that you would like to force him to see it, ie in the case of unique-location/tags you like them to see that for example its not Texas but Texas, United States or its not ajaxcontroltool but ajaxcontroltoolkit

Comment: From what i ve seen so far is that the autocomplete controls try to fetch data as lazy as possible as to not load the server and the javascript with alot of requests, so as soon as you stop pressing keys they tell you the answer. What Martin asks is kinda the opposite, to eagerly search and display results.

Comment: Yes, I would like the user to choose exactly which location they meant (the problem can be seen at www.ReviewYourRental.com) so I would always like the location list to appear even if the user has pressed 'Enter'.  I have noticed that HotelClub takes the user to a second page containing a list of nearest match cities but I would prefer to skip the second page and get the location correct on the first search page.  Thus I really need to sort out this 'Enter" key problem!  Any technical solutions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I've hacked around this problem before with an extra keydown handler on the textbox that is the target of the auto-complete. Replace `this._autoCompleteBehavior` in the snippet below with a reference to your instance of AutoCompleteBehavior (obtainable via `$find()` and the `BehaviorID`). The idea here is to force the auto-complete behavior to think it needs to perform a lookup by calling `_onTimerTick()`, which executes after the typing delay has expired. By default the typing delay gets cancelled by hitting the enter key, so this just forces the lookup anyway on enter or tab.

Disclaimer: my hack references "private" members of the AjaxControlToolkit code (stuff that starts with underscore is "private"), so it is probably not guaranteed to be future-proof.

```
_searchTextbox_keydown: function(e)
{
    var key = e.keyCode || e.rawEvent.keyCode;

    // If the user hits enter or tab before the auto complete popup appears, force the autocomplete lookup at that moment.        
    if ((key === Sys.UI.Key.enter || key === Sys.UI.Key.tab) && this._autoCompleteBehavior._currentPrefix != this._autoCompleteBehavior._currentCompletionWord())
    {
        this._autoCompleteBehavior._onTimerTick(this._autoCompleteBehavior._timer, Sys.EventArgs.Empty);

        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: for $find("AutoCompleteEx") to work you need to set BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx" on the AutoCompleteExtender xml tag

Answer (score -1):

Hey try jQuery or YUI autocomplete extender. It will be lightning fast.

Comment: No, it is not the speed I am after as AJAX Autocomplete is fine.  It is the fact that when the user presses "Enter", the list does does not appear.