# Simulate mouse click on a focused TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, textbox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is this possible? I have a button with onClick() Method. If i click the Button i want to simulate a mouse click event inside a TextBox. With Focus() i can focus inside the TextBox but how to simulate left mouse click?

**EDIT** I have an AutoCompleteExtender that should show a list of names in a certain TextBox after the user clicks a Button. The TextBox can work both:the user writes a character and the list appears or he clicks the button and a whole list appears.

**EDIT** I have used AjaxControlToolkit and from my experience i have to click on the TextBox if i want the list to appear even though i have a focis on the TextBox and MinimumPrefixLength=0

Comment: what exactly do you want? as it looks like you are creating a bigger problem than it should.

Comment: What is purpose of that?

Comment: Do you have an event handler for the mouse click and you just want to run the contents of that handler?

Comment: I hope you will get what you looking for if you refer this


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript

Comment: In C# you need reflection http://forums.asp.net/t/1046550.aspx

Comment: You are getting many -1s because your question is very unclear. What are you trying to do? I can only guess by the tags this is a website, do you want to use Javascript to achieve onClick or asp.net webforms event? Do you need the method to run on the clientside or serverside, etc...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8332950/360171

Answer (score 2):

Create a "logic" method where you do your work. When the user clicks on the TextBox, call your logic method. When you want to simulate a click, call your logic method also.

```
// Attach to the event
myTextBox.Click += new EventHandler(myTextBox_Click);
// Simulate a "click" event
MyLogic();

protected void myTextBox_Click(object o, EventArgs e) {
    MyLogic();
}

private void MyLogic() {
    // Do work
}
```

Comment: Spot on with that advice. +1 well deserved. Only point I'd suggest is move MyLogic to anotehr class so it can be independently unit tested.